# subsetting agentsets transforming a list of agents into an agentset

Tags: netlogo

A toy example. There are two groups of people: **A** and **B**. Only **A** can say "hello" to people **B**. People walk around the world and meet each other. When **people A** meet **people B**, they say hello to them. Each person *A* record who was said hello to and the tick when that occurred. They cannot say hello to the same person until five new ticks happen. The procedures below only apply to **people A**.

Each time a **person A** say hello to a **person B** I define:

```
set tick-last-greeting lput ticks tick-last-greeting
set previous-person-b-greeted lput selected-person-b previous-person-b-greeted
```

Before the say-hello procedure happens again:

```
if (length  tick-last-greeting != [] and previous-person-b-greeted != []) [
  ; wait 5 ticks
  set temp (map [ticks - ? > 5] tick-last-greeting)
  ; filter the list, I don't know if there is a better way to do this
  set previous-person-b-greeted (map last filter [first ? = false] (map list temp previous-person-b-greeted)) 
  set tick-last-greeting (map last filter [first ? = false] (map list temp tick-last-greeting))
]
```

So, I get a list of **people B** that shouldn't be greeted by a **person A** but until five ticks happen. Here is my key problem: how to define an agentset that excludes the agents of the list `previous-person-b-greeted`.

```
set potential-persons-b targets-on (patch-set neighbors patch-here)
if (previous-person-b-greeted > 0) [

; Here, I get an error as expected
let who-previous-person-b [who] of previous-person-b-greeted 
set potential-persons potential-persons with [who != who-previous-person-b]
]
```

A possible solution: transform the list `previous-person-b-greeted` into an agentset (I don't know if there is simple way to do this).

Any ideas?

Comment: First, if you have a `who` in your code, you are probably doing something in a way that is unnecessarily convoluted. Normally I would say just construct an agentset in the first place, but I think you do need the list because you are storing two pieces of information, agent and when greeted. I haven't fully thought this through, but I think I would be doing two lists - one for the agents and one for the whens - so it was easy to search through the whens list and use `position` to delete the information from both lists if tick-seen was too long ago...

Comment: ...Real programmers would probably do lists of pairs but I am not good enough with lists to describe how to filter those. With lists of agents, you can just use `member?` to see if agent B is in agent A's list of recent greetings.

Comment: I understand what you say, however, I wouldn't know exactly how to do it: I have an agentset, and a list with agents I want to remove. They have different lengths, that's why `who` seems to be the easiest way to find them. `member?` give me a true or false, probably `filter` could be useful.

Comment: Lists of agents are exactly the same length as lists of the who numbers of those agents, so using `who` gives you no benefit but adds coding to translate between the agent and its `who` number. The reason you want `member?` is that you only care whether they are in the list of agents - so T/F is correct. If they are in the list then they can't be greeted. And agents are removed from the list when their when-greeted gets too old. That is, you should only track agents met in the last 5 ticks, you don't need to keep a permanent memory of all agents ever met, just `remove-item`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To transform a list of agents into an agentset, use `turtle-set` or `patch-set` or `link-set`.  So e.g.:

```
observer> create-turtles 5
observer> let mylist (list turtle 0 turtle 2 turtle 4)  print turtle-set mylist
(agentset, 3 turtles)
```

Comment: Pretty simple :) It would be nice there was a document with some of those tricks!

Comment: The turtle-set primitive in the online documentation explicitly states that it can be used for lists, see http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#turtle-set

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you're not using specific breeds for people A or people B.

Perhaps you could try using **breeds**, for example:

```
breed [personA peopleA]
breed [personB peopleB]
```

Will define 2 different agentsets and then you can use the `<breeds>-own` statement to define a list of recently greeted people.

```
peopleA-own [recently-greeted-people recently-greeted-people-time]
```

And then everytime that a personA has to greet someone your procedure could look like this:

```
to greet [personB-who]
    if (not (and (member? personB-who recently-greeted-people)
                  (procedure-that-checks-ticks-less-than-5))
       ...ADD HERE OTHER LOGICAL CHECKS DEPENDING ON YOUR PROBLEM
       )
       [ 
         fput personB-who recently-greeted-people
         fput current-tick recently-greeted-people-time
       ]
end
```

Observe that for every `personB` greeted, the `who` and the `id` are added to different lists and then they must be removed at the same time to keep consistence.

You can read more about [breeds in the NLogo dictionary.](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#breed)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, following your suggestions, I ended up with this solution:

```
set potential-persons-b sort (targets-on (patch-set neighbors patch-here))

if (previous-person-b-greeted != []) 
[

foreach previous-victimized-target
[ set potential-persons-b remove ? potential-persons-b]

set potential-persons-b turtle-set potential-persons-b
]
```

Here a more general solution using `to-report`:

```
to-report subsetting-agents [agent-set1 agent-set2]
  set agent-set1 sort agent-set1
  set agent-set2 sort agent-set2
  foreach agent-set2
  [ set agent-set1 remove ? agent-set1]
  set agent-set1 turtle-set agent-set1
  report agent-set1
end
```